# Distinction in Control Styles for Lab Windows CVI

Tags: user-interface, labwindows, cvi

I'm creating some UI controls in Lab Windows CVI programmatically, and I saw on [NI's site](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370051V-01/cvi/uiref/cvicontrol_styles/) that there are two different graph types, "CTRL_GRAPH_LS" and "CTRL_GRAPH". Many other controls have the same suffix. What are the differences between the two?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***_LS*** is used to indicate *[Lab Style](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370051V-01/cvi/uiref/cviattrctrlstyle/)* controls.

Using one over the other is completely preferential.  The primary distinction is that *Lab Style* is a new style, as opposed to Classic, or old style.  Lab Style has a richer, 3D look, where the old style is flatter in appearance.  In terms of functionality, I have seen no advantage using one over the other.  When using the *[NewCtrl](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370051V-01/cvi/uiref/cvinewctrl/)* function to programmatically create your UI controls, you can select Lab Style controls by including the ***_LS*** suffix option for controls that offer it.